# Why does this systemd unit file generate an error "service has a bad unit file setting"?

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to write a user service:

```shellsession
$ systemctl --user start valheim.service
Failed to start valheim.service: Unit valheim.service has a bad unit file setting.
See user logs and 'systemctl --user status valheim.service' for details.
```

I minimized it slightly, with the same error resulting:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Valheim Server
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
RemainAfterExit=True
ExecStart = /bin/ls

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Unfortunately, due to [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/1328245), I can't seem to currently use `systemctl status` to further diagnose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces around `=`:

```
ExecStart=/bin/ls
```

Comment: I think another issue I had, which I didn't specify in the original post, was that the `valheim.service` was a symbolic link. I used a hard link instead.

Comment: Symlinks work fine, I use them all the time for systemd services (global and user), so that shouldn’t have been a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question for the same problem, but with a different reason and a different solution. Here is what happened in my case.

An example with an error:

```
ExecStart=~/script.sh
```

Corrected example:

```
ExecStart=/home/user/script.sh
```